# Servicestack and Sql Server Reporting Services and Snapshot

Tags: reporting-services, servicestack, snapshot

i'm investigating integrating ssrs with servicestack, but as i'm using the new razor release, there are no references to any asp.net or mvc assemblies in my projects, so hosting in an aspx file for example, is not possible, and i'd like to keep it that way. i'm also looking to avoid deploying to a dedicated ssrs reporting server if at all possible.

it occurs to me that the snapshot view rendered out by servicestack under certain circumstances (missing view etc) could possibly fulfill the required role and was wondering if there is any way of customising the html that is rendered out? would it make sense to go down this route? would it be better if I simply spent the time creating a custom view for each entity (along with all their attendant child entities) I want to report on?

Comment: for anyone interested, the only way I could see to do this reliably, was to deploy to a report server. then use the web service which the ssrs server exposes and call that from my servicestack service. then stream the response out to the browser client. an advantage (required, for me) of doing it this way was that certain report parameters, such as the customer/company guid, were not exposed, either on the client, or in the usual query string you'd have when accessing a report by url, as I injected them in my service. neither would they be discernible by fiddler for example.